# How to make an HTML grid which resizes to fit page width?

Tags: html, css

I have a variable number of links I want to write to a page programatically. I would rather not have a single long list, but tabulate the links in one or more columns. However I don't want to force a table with a specific number of columns... rather I want to specify the column width (or let each column auto-fit to the widest element).

Is this achievable using regular HTML/CSS? For reference I'm doing this in C# (.NET2) but if anyone wants a bash at code, any pseudo is fine - input is simply an array/list of strings I want to write to the page.

Comment: I believe you can use an _inlined_ list (`ul`) which each `li` will have a fixed width.

Comment: Hiya @John. What you've described is a general concept you'd like to see implemented, and Stackoverflow tends to be more about helping you debug problems with your code. Could you post what you've got so we can suggest ways about it?

Comment: Have a look at CSS3 columns. [Quirksmode Link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html): The behavior in "Test 2" might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of an *inlined* list. Think about an horizontal list where each item has a fixed width.

```
link1.....link2.....link3.....link4.....
link5.....link6.....link7.....link8.....
link9.....link10....link11....
```

And so on. All you need is to make your list (`ul`) inlined then each item (`li`) to have a fixed width.

Here is a working demo using Twitter Bootstrap (the concept is the same): http://jsfiddle.net/FXkYr/

**In case you don't want to use Twitter Bootstrap** here are the relevant HTML & CSS you will need to use:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  /* The following two lines is because IE is funny... */
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a better way but could you provide a self-contained example that doesn't rely on external files... I had to wade through the bootstrap CSS which made understanding the example more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/vYtBM/

There are loads of different ways you could do it though to be fair. Via an unordered list with anchor tags inside each LI would be another way.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Link #1</a>
    <a href="#">Link #2</a>
    <a href="#">Link #3</a>
    <a href="#">Link #4</a>
    <a href="#">Link #5</a>
    <a href="#">Link #6</a>
    <a href="#">Link #7</a>
    <a href="#">Link #8</a>
    <a href="#">Link #9</a>
</div>

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:960px;
}

.container a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 440px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but I have to hard-code the element width. I can manage with that if I have to.

Comment: You could set it to just be percentages. The padding and background I've used are just to illustrate the layout but obviousl.y you can amend all of that to suit your needs.