# CSS columns not working when viewing HTML file on network share

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a fairly simple columns approach based on a list as described here: [How to make an HTML grid which resizes to fit page width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833056/how-to-make-an-html-grid-which-resizes-to-fit-page-width)

It works well on my local machine but when viewing the file over a network share, everything is just in one big column. All CSS is in the HTML file, no external scripts at all. I'm using IE9 in both cases so why the different behaviour?

Comment: Does it work if you use a browser other than IE9?

Comment: It's corporate so we pretty much only use IE9 but I'll test on Chrome and report back ;)

Comment: Any 404 not found ? Sounds like your ressources relativity is in fault.

Comment: Come on guys, IE9 is hardly a niche product!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the example link and the corresponding JSFiddle, accepted answer uses linked stylesheet resource: bootstrap-combined.min.css.  Which is accessible here:  http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css

I'm guessing, somewhere in your network, when the file is accessed, the user/IIS/whatever agent doesn't have rights to access the bootstrap file OR it wasn't included with an FTP publish.

Every `<ul>` I've ever worked with has the `<li>`'s set to clear:both by default.  By setting `<ul class="inline">`, it's made all the child elements inline elements which will float left by default, which is defined (apparently) in the twitter bootstrap.  So it's voo-doo css to me.

You could try setting the `<li>`'s class style to `float:left;`.  That will give you the desired result.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywVWD/1/

Comment: As I said in the post, everything is contained in the single HTML file - I used the separated bits in the accepted answer not the jsfiddle version.

Comment: You can have the answer just for a less confusing CSS setup :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what it was?